# Diablo 3 PS4 Drowned Temple issue

Tags: diablo-iii, ps4

I have an issue with my game, don't remember what suppose to happen but after entering Drowned Temple and clearing it down I have no quests, no markers, no objectives and I'm pretty much stuck. What should I do next?

[image]

[image]

Restart / reboot didn't help, trying to reinstall game altogether.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end of the temple after clearing it, you're supposed to find the 2nd sword fragment of the stranger (exactly where you're standing on your screenshot).

After taking it, you're supposed to bring it back to Deckard Cain in New Tristram.

[Here's a site](https://www.diablowiki.net/The_Broken_Blade) that lets you check every step of *The Broken Blade* quest.

If there wasn't the sword fragment in *Drowned Temple* or that there isn't an ongoing event when back to New Tristram, it seems that your game is bugged.
In this case, you should try to stop and launch again the game.

Comment: Can I edit this post instead of creating one?

Comment: @BartekMalysz if you have an answer, you'll want to create your own.

Comment: @BartekMalysz If you have found the solution, then you can create another answer to this question. That's perfectly fine.

Comment: @BartekMalysz Have you tried to check that every previous step before getting the fragment was well done? You might want to try and go back to check if Lea did give you the quest properly. If this still doesn't work you might start the quest over through options before starting the game, where you can select your character. I'll check tonight the exact options to reset a quest on PS4 and add this to the answer. Also sorry for suggesting you create a new question, seems like it wasn't a good idea :/

Comment: @Zoma You can see [this Arqade Meta Q&A](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/15950/250180) for more details on what the best course of action is.